# Opening up ports in Windows Server 2012 Firewall for Web Services

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-firewall, web-services

I have a website that has been migrated to a new server running Windows Server 2012 but it needs two ports opened so that it can access security web services on another server. I can open up the two ports via Windows Firewall Manager but how can I restrict the traffic only from a particular URL to the web services. What's the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the properties windows for the Firewall rule there is a `Scope` tab. Here you can specify the remote IP addresses for which the rule is valid, and therefor restrict the open ports to certain clients.

You can allow groups or addresses but not host names.